# Check if user is logged in to Facebook - Customer Chat Plugin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-messenger

I'm trying to figure out a way to check if a user is logged in to Facebook before I render the Customer Chat Plugin.
It doesn't matter to me to know who is the user etc., just whether he is logged in at all.

I tried to explore most of the `FB` object properties but didn't come up with anything.

I tried later to use `FB.init` and `FB.getLoginStatus` but the widget disappears when I use it (and I'm not sure it will give me the result I'm asking for)

Answer (score 0):

That´s possible with `FB.getLoginStatus`, you will get the status "not_authorized" if he is logged in on Facebook. I assume you want to load the plugin dynamically, so you have to use this after checking the status: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse/

Comment: I have seen that when a person is not connected to Facebook I'm getting `status: unknown` and If he is I'm getting `status:"not_authorized"`

Comment: updated. btw, you really need to include the relevant code - my answer is a guess because that happened a lot already, but it would be a lot more clear if you would add your code in the question. ALWAYS do that.

Comment: sure, do you have any idea why when I'm using `FB.init` the widget disappears? or how to launch it once again?

Comment: check out my answer, it is just a guess, as i said. without your code, it´s impossible to tell you something else.